# when is keyboard stream data stored in buffer?

Tags: c, stream, buffer

I'm studying about standard I/O streams and standard I/O functions in C.

And I found There are two incompatible explains about the buffer in stdin.

1. Whenever keys are pressed for each character, those data are stored in buffer immediately. And when you press enter, those are transmit to process
2. Data will be stored in buffer only after typing string and pressing enter. And data stored in buffer are taken when process needs it.

Could you tell me which above explained point is correct?
I'm really confused.

Comment: There is more than one buffer, so both statements are correct.

Comment: Not necessarily after pressing enter I guess. The characters are stored in buffer immediately (this is default behavior, but can probably be changed) and process should be able to use the data from the buffer.

Comment: I mean the buffer with standard input stream. I want to know how that buffer works

Comment: Imagine you hold a key down for several seconds ... How are the repeated "keys" generated/processed??? Is it the keyboard hardware circuitry? Does the keyboard itself have an internal buffer? There could be buffers at the keyboard itself, at the hardware level where the keyboard connects to the computer, at the kernel level where the Operating System connects to the hardware, at an intermediate level between the Operating System and the application, ..., ... Maybe, very possibly, **all of the above**.

Answer (score 0):

The terminal or console program have its own buffers. The operating system have its own buffers. And your program have its own buffers.

The keystrokes are stored by the terminal or console program, and is usually not sent to the operating system until the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed.

The operating system then stores the data internally, until requested by the C stdio functions.

The C stdio function then stores the data it have received from the operating system in its own internal buffers inside your process.

A finally your program reads the data from the stdio buffers.

Comment: *`"The keystrokes are stored by the terminal or console program, and is usually not sent to the operating system until the Enter key is pressed."`* 40+y ago maybe yes when VTxxx terminals were used